# Is it possible to create and instantiate an object using java reflect without class definition?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to create and instantiate an object which the type is not defined (no class definition)

```
Class table = Class.forName(dbTable.getName());
Constructor<?> ctor = table.getConstructor(String.class);
Object tableObject = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] {ListColumn});
```

here there is no a class definition named `dbTable.getName()` value.
So I have a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Is there a method solving this kind of issues.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What do you want to do with that object?

Comment: What would you do with such an object? You don't know what methods it has, or what fields it has

Comment: @k5_ i have a List<DbTable>, i want to create an object for each one of these dbTables, but the DbTable is not the same every time. And i have not any information about it (fields, methods...)

Comment: @Joni i have not any information about it

Comment: Let's take another approach. What concrete things do you want to do with these objects that represent database tables? Can't you just use the name of the table as a placeholder?

Comment: @BARHOUMI so just do `new Object();` for each row

Comment: @k5_ i want an object with w specific name new Object(); will create an object but i want this Object with name dbTable.getName().

Comment: @Joni for each one i want to set another list of Map<String, String> but his name must be the dbTable.getName() every time.

Comment: The usual way of solving this is to actually create the class that you call `Class.forName( dbTable.getName() );`  Some frameworks will auto-generate those classes, which is a big time saver, otherwise you must create the class manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create instances of unknown classes. You need **one** class that can represent database tables as objects

```
public class DBTable {
    String tableName;
    Map<String, String> columns; // I don't know what you wanted to do with this?

    public String toString() {
        return "Table " + tableName;
    }
}
```